# Given an x coordinate, how do I delete a line from an array of lines which has that x coordinate

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I have a bunch of stored lines that are just vertical in an array called H, like so:

```
h(1)=plot([10,10][750,1000])
h(2)=plot([20,20][750,1000])
h(3)=plot([30,30][750,1000])
```

I know that to delete the second plot, i would do: delete(h(2)) followed by h(2)=[]. The problem is, I don't know the index of 20. Let's say I have the number 20 stored, is there a way to get the location of my vector h where there is a line with an x value of 20 to delete?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
h(2).XData(20) = [];
h(2).YData(20) = [];
```

---

Example:

```
X = 1:5;Y = 1:5;
h = plot(X, Y, 'o');grid on;
```

[image]

```
h.XData(3) = [];h.YData(3) = [];
```

[image]